# Chance to find a job in Amsterdam, NL?

Tags: eu, netherlands, relocation, job-hunting

I am a graphic designer + front-end developer and have more than 8 years of experience in both majors. I am a Turkish citizen who is married to Bulgarian (EU Citizen) wife.

Do I have a chance to find a job and move to Amsterdam as a Expat worker or something like that?

Comment: Hi Onur and welcome to Expats.SE. The simple answer is - yes it's possible.

Comment: Thank you Dirty-flow. So what is the best point to start? Seeking jobs, find people who did this before or something else. I need some advices.

Comment: https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/work/highly-skilled-migrant could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In the Netherlands, I would say just as anywhere, it is hard to find good people for tech jobs. If you're good in your profession, it should be easy to find a job.

Two places which might help you start:

- [Fronteers](https://fronteers.nl/vacaturebank) (in Dutch) an organization which helps frontend developers and has vacancies listed for that area.
- [Dutch Startup jobs](http://dutchstartupjobs.com/) vacancy listing for the Dutch (and Belgium) startup scene, mostly tech jobs.

Good luck finding a nice place, and have fun!